# Set up WLAN in 3-level house

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm having a hard time setting up the network in our house. It has three levels (basement, ground floor, first level).

The WLAN is set up by an ASUS RT-N12 router which provides perfect coverage for the ground floor and the basement. However, I set up my "home office" in the basement where the signal barely arrived.

So I purchased a TP-Link TL-WA901ND (300 Mbps) Access Point which I set up in the other corner of the ground floor to expand the ASUS router's range. I used the AP's Repeater mode for that. The distance between my computer and the TP-Link AP is 6-7 meters. There is a staircase going down from the ground floor to the basement so there are no solid walls between the computer and the AP.

This setup mostly works (I am writing this from the basement) but it is not reliable (the signal strength sometimes goes down to ~40% of the max) sometimes so I wonder if I am doing it correctly or if there is a better way.

Screenshot of the router's and the AP's dashboard screen follow:

[image: Router dashboard]
[image: AP dashboard]

Any comments on what I am doing wrong or hints for improvement are appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Tried one more thing, setting up the TP-LINK AP in Access Point mode. That way, I can make it use a different SSID. I enabled WDS/Bridge so that it expands the range of the ASUS router (see screenshot). That does not work, either, if I connect to the network set up by the TP-LINK device (PELSTER-2), I can't reach the external network (the Internet). It seems the problem always comes back to this, the TP-LINK does not have access to the external network, whatever its mode of operation.

[image]

Comment: `The WLAN is set up by an ASUS RT-N12 router which provides perfect coverage for the ground floor and the basement. However, I set up my "home office" in the basement where the signal barely arrived` - This statement contradicts itself. Either the signal coverage in the basement is good or it isn't.

Comment: While you can use the same SSID, I don't suggest doing so.  Some appliances when roaming will not switch properly.  Change the name of your remote wifi devices to something different and try again.  It will make it easier to debug and work out what is going on.

Comment: @joeqwerty Sorry, I was sloppy. I meant "which provides perfect coverage for the ground floor and the *first floor*".

Comment: It does not seem like I have the option to change the SSID of the TP-LINK AP in Repeater mode. It just "copies" the settings from the ASUS router.

Comment: FWIW, what ended up working is setting the TP-LINK AP to Access Point mode, turning off the DHCP server on it, connecting its LAN port to one of the LAN ports of the route and assigning a different SSID and channel to it. I still don't full get why I need to physically connect

Answer (score 1):

First, as it is well described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#2.4.C2.A0GHz_.28802.11b.2Fg.2Fn.29  , you should use not all Wifi-Channels at the same time. As your TP-Link screenshot shows, it is running on channel 6. Therefore the ASUS-router should use channel 1 or 11 (you have to configure this manually), depends on which channels are less used in your local area (simply Google an app for that). The problem with the channels is: If A tries to send a package on channel 2 and B is already sending a package on channel 6, A have to wait until B makes a pause so A can start sending. If you use 1, 6, 11 nobody (neither the ASUS-router nor the TP-Link-router) has to wait for the other one to finish sending.

Second, maybe your antenna is not good enough. By a larger one or if you want to build it by your own, try to extend it with a wire: Twist it around the original antenna (simply five times around the plastic) and let a 5 feet (1.5 meter) long "self-made-antenna" extend the range.

Thirdly, try to relocate the router. I have personally used http://www.netspotapp.com/ (Mac only) to make a map of my wireless-network-coverage.  (I don't know the company, it's just a great, free app - if it is not allowed to post such a link on superuser.com please notify me or edit my answer) 
With the map I knew where the coverage was really bad (cause by the walls / wires / shafts) and where I should put my routers.

Forth, maybe your PC has a bad Wifi-Card. Try to connect the PC directly with the LAN-port of the TP-Link (buy a 6 meters (20 feet) cable or relocate the TP-Link router).

Hope I could help, if not detailed enough, simply ask!

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. Unfortunately I can't seem to set the a different channel for the TP-LINK AP. Since it is a repeater it just copies the settings from the router, including the SSID and the channel.

Comment: A few other things that came to mind: I use DHCP in the main router to distribute IP addresses. I enabled the DHCP server in the AP, too, but I'm not sure if this is needed/right. Also, the built-in ping utility in the browser can't even reach an IP address I know responds to ping.

Comment: I don't think the wifi card is an issue, I have a MacBook Pro. Relocating the router or using a long network cable could both be good solutions but would need more "architecture" work, something I want to stay away from, if I can. I thought using a repeater solves this exact problem.

Comment: You should disable DHCP on the Access Point, because it is an access point! And: There has to be an settings-option for the channel, otherwise it would be strange... And according to this english manual from tp-link [link](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/200912243240113.pdf) (page 26) it is possible to change it!

Comment: And if you really want to avoid "architecture work", try to map your house with netspot! It is a great, free tool and maybe you just have to move 1 meter and everything works fine, due to an very strong pillar in your wall... The app helped me a lot when I had to set up a Wifi for an whole concert hall in Austria! And: MacBooks are build to be light and small, therefore Apple is not able to put the best, largest and heaviest antenna in their unibody-engineering-marvel!

Comment: NetSpot app is a killer app and I found a corner of the basement where the signal is strong enough to get a stable connection, thank you! The professional curiosity cannot let me have my peace, though. The problem with the TP-Link AP is that whatever its mode of operation, it cannot access the external network. I know this because if I ping 8.8.8.8 (or a host I know responds to ping) I get no response back. I suspect I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of what an AP can do? Can't it connect to the ISP's incoming cable and allow other devices to connect to the Internet? (ext. network)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, what ended up working is setting the TP-LINK AP to Access Point mode, turning off the DHCP server on it, connecting its LAN port to one of the LAN ports of the ASUS router and assigning a different SSID and channel to it.

I still don't full get why I can't connect to the router "via air" (WLAN) so if anyone can shed a light on this, that would be great.